# Disabling deployed Web services through Java code

Tags: web-services, glassfish, jax-ws

I work with JAX-WS Web services deployed on to a Glassfish Web server and Netbeans IDE. We have provisions to disable or undeploy a Web service deployed onto a Glassfish Web server using admin console or services tab in the IDE. This looks to be some sort of hardware interrupt. I would like to achieve the same, i.e. disabling a deployed Web service through Java code, on some external command from interface. Is there any mechanism to obtain such outcome through software interrupts or by any other means?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep configuration settings like discoveryAllowed attribute at server side may be like in DB.
On which you can decide whether to allow user to call web-methods. Add beelow code in web-method:

If **discoveryAllowed** is **false** then call following code:

```
MessageContext mc = context.getMessageContext();
HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_RESPONSE);
resp.setContentType("text/plain");
resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "Web service is disabled.");
```

If **discoveryAllowed** is **true** allow to proceed with code execution.